# Doctrine 2.0 - Hydrating to array rather than object when viewing information

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I have a bit of a question that has been bothering me for a while. I am using Doctrine 2.0 for a number of projects that I am working on, and I have hit a bit of a ponderous issue.

In most of the projects frontend applications I am hydrating to arrays rather than objects; by which I mean when I produce a doctrine query I might do this:

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $entityManager->getQueryBuilder();
$query->select('something', 'somethingElse')
      ->from('My\Entity\Location', 'something')
      ->leftJoin('something.somethingelse', 'somethingElse')
      ->where('something.id = :someId')
      ->setParameter('someId', $someId)
      ->getQuery();

$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Now this is what I am doing for ALL of the code that is on the front end of our application because hydrating to an array is a lot faster than hydrating to an object. Now my question is this: If I am using Doctrine should I not really be using `getResult()` and then passing the entities returned to a view and interacting with them there?

I use `getResult` or `getSingleResult` when I am say in the administration area and I am making a change to an entity; however it just feels a little odd using the incredibly heavy Doctrine just to retrieve information into an array on the frontend - something I could do with a simple PDO anyway?!?

Hope I have made my question clear enough.

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine does additional validation and makes the join condition a little easier to write. This convenience may not be free, but it might still be good when considering long term maintenance. If you are worried about performance, I would advise you do some profiling to see how expensive it really is. When all caching is enabled in Doctrine, it does not turn out to be much more expensive than direct queries.

There is nothing wrong with going directly to SQL if you really need that extra performance boost, but I would advise against optimizing before you have evidence that this is really where the problem lies through profiling.